# jamvm1.5+classpath-0.96+qt4.3 QPixmap: It is not safe to use pixmaps outside the GUI thread

Tags: qt, classpath, qpixmap, jamvm

```
jamvm -Dawt.toolkit=gnu.java.awt.peer.qt test

QPixmap: It is not safe to use pixmaps outside the GUI thread
```

I'm new to Qt, I don't know how to deal with it.

Comment: Are you asking a question, or just stating that you don't know what to do?  Also, it usually helps to show some of the code that is generating the error message (or warning).

Answer (score 1):

I have no experience whatsoever with the jamvm, but here's the [Qt doc](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qpixmap.html#details) quote that might be helpful:

> Qt provides four classes for handling
>   image data: QImage, QPixmap, QBitmap
>   and QPicture. QImage is designed and
>   optimized for I/O, and for direct
>   pixel access and manipulation, while
>   QPixmap is designed and optimized for
>   showing images on screen.

Try using QImage instead of QPixmap and see if there is the same warning/error message.

Answer (score 1):

Since QPixmap is a device-dependent representation, and many display drivers and systems aren't thread-safe, QPixmap is restricted to only being used in the main or GUI thread, which is the same thread your QApplication object should be instantiated in.  You can see a brief bit in [the documentation here](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.4/threads.html#painting-in-threads), and read more information about it in [this discussion thread](http://www.archivum.info/qt-interest@trolltech.com/2008-11/00729/RE:-QPixmap:-It-is-not-safe-to-use-pixmaps-outside-the-GUI-thread.html).